# is possible to read a URL compressed with gzip (tvs.gz) with CSVProvider in F#?

Tags: f#, f#-data

is possible to read a URL compressed with gzip (tvs.gz) with CSVProvider in F#? Im trying with this code:

```ml
type name = CsvProvider<"https://datasets.imdbws.com/name.basics.tsv.gz", "\t">
```

But, I'm getting this error:

The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.CsvProvider' reported an error: Cannot read sample CSV from 'https://datasets.imdbws.com/name.basics.tsv.gz': Couldn't parse row 1 according to schema: Expected 2 columns, got 1

So, is possible to use a type provider in F# to do easy analisys over compressed CSVs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to decompress the file with something like `GZipStream`, before being able to read it with `CsvProvider`.

Comment: Hmm, it would be awesome if possible to do this in streaming fashion, directly.

Comment: I assume its possible to do this as a stream, but the CSV provider needs at least one row of the uncompressed csv. The decompression and streaming would be handled elsewhere